# Auto provisioning system for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, chef-infra, provisioning

I've built a simple application, and I want to sell access to it. I was wondering about any gems or tools that could allow me to auto-provision a rails application and database without me manually touching anything.

Thank you for every advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). It's the closest thing to what you're asking for without having to do anything special.

Comment: But I want to my own auto-provision system. Do you have any idea how to it?

Comment: What about Chef, Capistrano?

Comment: Rolling your own auto-provisioning system is not exactly easy. As they say, the first 80% of the work is easy, but it's the remaining 800% that's really, really hard. Chef and Capistrano are tools to help with automation, but they do not automatically provision anything. Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk, which is both powerful and tricky to use effectively, could be a component of this system...or you could just use Heroku.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I need my own auto-provision system. Do you know any good resource?